# Why doesn't caching work without CacheManager if I have @EnableCaching?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am learning caching, article says thay `@EnableCaching` is enough for Spring to automatically create a simple cache manager under the hood.
But if I do a simple test of a method - exception pops up.

Method

```
    @Cacheable("example")
public DishResponseDTO getOne(int dishId) {
    var dish = dishRepository.findById(dishId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(dishtErrorMessage(dishId)));
    return DishMapper.toDishResponseDTO(dish);
}
```

Test

```
    @Test
@Transactional
public void get() {
    System.out.println(dishService.getOne(1));
    System.out.println(dishService.getOne(2));
    System.out.println(dishService.getOne(1));
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'example' for Builder[public com.topjava.graduation.restaurant.dto.DishResponseDTO com.topjava.graduation.restaurant.service.DishService.getOne(int)] caches=[example] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
```

When I add a simple Cache Manager - exception disappears and everything works fine.

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<Cache>();
        caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache("dto"));
        cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
}
```

If I remove `@EnableCaching` - nothing changes. So the question is what is the point of `@EnableCaching` annotation if no simple cache manager is created?

Comment: What article? Spring's [`@EnableCaching documentation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html) states *"**A bean of type `CacheManager` must be registered**, as there is no reasonable default that the framework can use as a convention."*

Comment: Thank you, but why does my caching still work without EnableCaching annotation? I still have only one DB call, when the same method is requested 3 times.



Here is a link
[link](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-cache-example/)